# Copy two files with same name using ROBOCOPY

Tags: c#, .net, robocopy

I'm searching for a particular file in the machine and copying them to specific location using robocopy programmatically. Now the problem is if i'm searching for a file named `copy.txt` and both `E:\Temp` and `E:\test` has copy.txt once I copy using Robocopy only one file is copied. Is there any option in Robocopy by which they get copied as `copy.txt` and `copy(1).txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `robocopy` sadly **does not** have any option to copy, and keep both files. You would have to use `PowerShell` or something like that.